# unit test runs with python but fails with nosetests

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I have written a python file containing some unit tests (testfile.py).

When I run 'python testfile.py' the tests run fine and there are no errors.

But when I run 'nosetests testfile.py', I get a TypeError of the form 
TypeError: func_name() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given).

Can you please help me understand what might be going on and how can I modify the python file so that it can be run using both python and nosetests.
Thanks in advance,
Ambarish.

Comment: Please add the minimum amount of code you can show that reproduces this error

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you're getting hung on how discovery works differently on the different tools. It trips me up all the time. Go into the directory with your tests and do:

$ nosetests testfile

(no .py on the end of testfile)

You can also use the python unittest module:

$ python -m unittest testfile

Comment: Hi Iain, I did try both nosetests testfile and python -m unittest testfile. While the latter works, the former does not and yields the same error as before. Thanks, Ambarish.

Comment: Ah, you might need need an empty _ _ init _ _ .py in the directory so it get's perceived as a module. Give that a try? If that doesn't work, maybe post the contents of your test file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. I had a non-test function which included 'test' in its name even it id did not start with 'test_', as a result of which it was treated as a test function by nose. When I modified the name of the function, the problem was solved.